# How to bind WindowsCommands with Caliburn.Micro in Metro?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I just added the `MahApps.Metro` WPF UI package to an existing WPF application, for which I use `Caliburn.Micro`. In my `MainView` I had a menu with buttons, which switched the content of the main area of the UI, as follows:

```
<DockPanel>
     <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" Name="ShowHomeVM">
</DockPanel>
```

and in the `MainViewModel`, I have the following method bound by naming convention,

```
public void ShowHomeVM() {
    CentralVM = HomeVM;
}
```

and the `CentralVM` view model instance is bound to the content of the window.
Now, with Metro I'd like to move my menu to the windows title bar as follows

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button Name="ShowHomeVM" Content="Home"/>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
```

and that works, except Caliburn does not bind the button to the method in the view model anymore.

How should one bind methods to buttons in the title bar with caliburn.micro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does indeed not go with built-in features of Caliburn.Micro. Instead of changing the internals of the framework which was suggested by @Keith, I just wired up the buttons by hand, namely in my `MainView` I define buttons as follows,

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button Content="Home" Command="{Binding HomeCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Import" Command="{Binding ImportCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Players" Command="{Binding PlayerCommand}"/>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
```

Here I am binding the `Command` property to Commands in the `MainViewModel`, which looks as follows,

```
public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase {

    // ... other stuff ... 

    public ICommand HomeCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand PlayerCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand ImportCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {

        // ... other stuff ... //

        HomeCommand = new RelayCommand(o => CentralVM = HomeVM, o => true);
        PlayerCommand = new RelayCommand(o => CentralVM = PlayersVM, o => true);
        ImportCommand = new RelayCommand(o => CentralVM = ImportVM, o => true);
    }
}
```

As for the `RelayCommand` class, I am using the implementation given [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/). The first argument in the constructor is the action that the command should execute, the second is whether it should be able to execute it - which I want to be always true for menu buttons (for now).

Answer (score 2):

I found out that Caliburn.Micro can still help, maybe not as comfortable as binding by name, but you can use the Message.Attach from the caliburnproject namespace.

I did it like this:

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"

<Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button Content="Home" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ShowHomeVM()]"/>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Caliburn.Micro can't handle these situations. Your only options are:

1. Fork the Caliburn.Micro source and fix it yourself.
2. Drop Caliburn.Micro and use a different MVVM framework.

Comment: But where is the conceptual difference of binding to controls in the title of a window? There must be a way...

Comment: Also, when you say 'fix it yourself', could you be more specific what the problem is?

Comment: CM's weakness is that its automatic conventions don't work properly in custom controls. You will need to fork the CM source, and debug this issue yourself. I dropped CM about 4 years ago, so I can't be more specific than that. I apologize.

Comment: Could I manually bind the commands from the title bar then, somehow? How would you manually bind them (without CM)?